# Clang Analyser hints for tracking leaks

Tags: c, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I'm working on a small library where it is convenient for me to have slice objects as we know them from Go or Rust; these are essentially a pointer and a length, and I can use these to pass sub-chunks of arrays around.

```c
struct slice {
    size_t len;
    char *buf;
};
```

They are supposed to be passed by value, and they make a number of algorithms a lot easier to manage.

Of course, sometimes I also need to allocate the memory for the buffers they are slices off, and in a few different attempts at designs for that, I keep running into problems with clang's static analyzer. It is really hard to get it to track that I am allocating new memory without also assuming that I haven't *initialized* said memory.

I figured out that I could tell the analyzer that I have allocated memory with `__attribute__((ownership_returns(malloc))` (but I have found no documentation for this, so I don't really know what I am doing there).

With code such as this:

```c
struct slice *alloc_slice(size_t len) __attribute__((ownership_returns(malloc)));

void foo(void)
{
    struct slice *x = alloc_slice(100);
    if (x->len > 10) { // I promise you, this isn't uninitialised
        printf("foo!\n");
    }
    // Leak here
}
```

the analyzer will generally know that I have allocated memory for `x`, but it will assume that it is uninitialised, so it considers looking at `x->len` an error.

Is there any way to tell clang that I have allocated *and initialised* memory? It can handle it with `calloc`, so it should be able to. But is it something I can also do with my own functions?

I figured out that the analyzer could also see that I am using `malloc` if it can see the function in the compilation unit, for example by inlining it. So that was another attempt. The initialisation isn't that complicated, so I could live with that. However, the damned thing doesn't consider it a leak if I do this:

```c
struct slice_buf {
    struct slice slice;
    char data[];
};

struct slice *alloc_slice_2(size_t len)
{
    struct slice_buf *buf = malloc(offsetof(struct slice_buf, data) + len);
    buf->slice.len = len;
    buf->slice.buf = buf->data;
    return (struct slice *)buf;
}

void bar(void)
{
    struct slice *x = alloc_slice_2(100);
    if (x->len > 10) { // I promise you, this isn't uninitialised
        printf("foo!\n");
    }
    // Leak here, but not detected
}
```

The problem, as far as I have managed to track it down, is the assignment `buf->slice.buf = buf->data`. The analyzer is a little too conservative here, and assumes that I am not leaking `buf` if there is a pointer inside `buf` that points to something inside `buf`. This is sensible, I have used a pointer into a member of a structure to manage the memory of the full structure in the past, and I wouldn't like that to be considered an error. It is just annoying here. If I don't assign to `buf->slice.buf`, then the analyzer detects a leak

```c
struct slice *alloc_slice_3(size_t len)
{
    struct slice_buf *buf = malloc(offsetof(struct slice_buf, data) + len);
    buf->slice.len = len;
    // I need this, but the analyzer gets confused: buf->slice.buf = buf->data;
    return (struct slice *)buf;
}

void baz(void)
{
    struct slice *x = alloc_slice_3(100);
    if (x->len > 10) { // I promise you, this isn't uninitialised
        printf("foo!\n");
    }
    // Leak here, and now detected
}
```

but then, of course, the slice is also useless.

Is there any way that I can just annotate a function to say that what it returns must be freed, but trust me, it is initialised memory?

If you want to play with the code I have listed here, you can get it at Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/31Gh9qWMj

**Update**

I thought I would try another thing, but that makes the situation a little worse. My thinking was that if I could hide the initialisation from the analyser, maybe it would accept that the memory was initialised, and with a little luck it would still consider the pointer as something that must freed. Well, it halfway worked.

```c
struct slice_buf {
    struct slice slice;
    char data[];
};
// Hiding the initialisation from the compiler...
void init_buf(struct slice_buf *buf, size_t len);
struct slice *alloc_slice_4(size_t len)
{
    struct slice_buf *buf = malloc(offsetof(struct slice_buf, data) + len);
    init_buf(buf, len);
    return (struct slice *)buf;
}

void qux(void)
{
    struct slice *x = alloc_slice_4(100);
    if (x->len > 10) { // This is fine 
        printf("foo!\n");
    }
    // Now the leak goes unnoticed once again
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3EWxGeYnY

It accepts that the memory is initialised, but assumes that the pointer is freed in the function I call. To be fair, a conservative analyser must assume this, as I might have called a destructor function, but it isn't the case here.

It is getting a little frustrating that the analyser only checks for leaks until you look at the pointer the wrong way, and I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong here. It cannot possibly be the case that the checker so easily assumes that the memory is taken care of. But I have no idea whatsoever on how to annotate my functions to help the analyser do the right thing.

**Update Update**

Then I ran into another set of attributes that looked like they were designed for exactly this purpose: `acquire_handle`, `use_handle` and `release_handle`. Unfortunately, as far as I can see they are completely ignored. The compiler knows about them (at least `-Wunknown-attributes` doesn't complain), but the static analyser doesn't care.

```c
[[clang::acquire_handle("slice")]]
struct slice *alloc_slice(size_t len);
[[clang::use_handle("slice")]]
void use_slice(struct slice *slice);
[[clang::release_handle("slice")]]
void free_slice(struct slice *slice);

void foo(void)
{
    struct slice *x = alloc_slice(100);
    use_slice(x);
    // Leak here -- not noticed
}

void bar(void)
{
    struct slice *x = alloc_slice(100);
    use_slice(x);
    // Freed twice, not noticed
    free_slice(x);
    free_slice(x);
}
```

(see https://godbolt.org/z/azx9ahEqj)

Since these attributes are so obviously useful for static analysis, I expect that I am simply running the analyser wrong, but I have no clue as to what I am supposed to be doing to get it to work.